# Is there a simple WISA version of a LAMP-in-a-box app such as apache2triad?

Tags: lamp, wisa

Is there a simple WISA version of a LAMP-in-a-box app such as apache2triad?

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing I guess would be to use the Microsoft Web Platform Installer:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/Downloads/platform.aspx

From that interface you can check the boxes for IIS, .net Framework (if those aren't already on your system) and MS SQL 2008 Express.